# Mark the first two rows with a value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle view which contains employee's attendance records including late attendance days.

Columns:

- Employee Number
- Date
- In-Time
- Out-time
- Late_Arrival (if late currently getting marked as 1)

I want to mark each employees first two late arrivals of a month as "G" from a query.

Please help me with this.

Sample data as below link tps://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Xw1eXeLyG7akZuTEdDUGNIUDg

Comment: Have you tried a query already?  SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Yes tim. I know that. But could not find a possible way. Thats why i looked for a help. Sorry if this is a wrong forum for that.

Comment: As Tim stated, you should post what you tried, sample data, etc.

Comment: Please find the sample data from below link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Xw1eXeLyG7akZuTEdDUGNIUDg

Comment: Don't post links to some download location. **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something for `row_number()` and some date arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when late_arrival = 1 and
                  row_number() over (partition by trunc(date, 'MON'), late_arrival
                                     order by date, intime
                                    ) <= 2
             then 'G'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you . Please find my table sample here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Xw1eXeLyG7akZuTEdDUGNIUDg

Comment: Hi @Gordon, any luck on my matter ?